# Return a value created in an event handler inside a function from the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have an input box and a go button. When the user clicks the go button I want to compare the inserted value with another value. I am trying to acquire the input value inside a function like so

```
function getInput(){
        var entry ='';
        $('button.go').on('click',function(){
            var entry = $(this).siblings('.input').val();
            //return entry
        })
        return entry


}
```

Basically I want to return the var entry that has an input value, so I could compare the values later in the code

```
var input = getInput() // this should have input value
is input > othervalue
```

I call getInput inside document.ready()

Comment: Please add your HTML too!

Comment: i made it dynamically. It's just an input and a button. `$container.append('<input class="input">').append('<button class= "go">GO</button>')`

Comment: Yup. That's also needed! `:)`

Comment: You do understand the `$('button.go').on('click')` is to bind the click event to the element? The callback function will only be executed when `button.go` gets clicked. This can be quite some time after you've called `getInput()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything right . There are some scope related issues that is not helping you to get the expected result . My suggestion would be to define `othervalue` variable as global and check it inside the function like this

```
function getInput(){       
    $('button.go').on('click',function(){
       var entry = $(this).siblings('.input').val();     
        if(entry>othervalue) //your code     
    });     
}
```

I am not sure why you are binding dynamic `click` event inside a function . If there is nothing else you need to do here except this part, then wrap this piece of code inside `document.ready`.

Comment: I was wondering if you could look at the fiddle in this comment. its not great code but it just displays random numbers on the screens adds them up and compares them to user input. I dont know if your snippet will work for me because i would like to try to have a compare function that compares returned value (entry) to the value from the adding up function  http://jsfiddle.net/u3wu7wh8/ how could i do something like `function compare(){` in the fiddle is it possible to return a value from an  event that's inside a function?

Comment: @user2537537 Well I gave a little hand to your code . Hope the things should go this way only . I removed some codes what I thought redundant . http://jsfiddle.net/u3wu7wh8/3/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to declare your `var entry ='';` globally and assign it before comparing.

```
var entry="";
$('button.go').on('click',function(){
     entry = $(this).siblings('.input').val();
});
//do the comparing..
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the comparing, after **delegating** the click function, inside the function.

```
var entry = "";
$('button.go').on('click', function(){
     var entry = $(this).prev('.input').val();
     if (entry < x)
         // Do something
});
```

Comment: hi I tried writing out why i think this wouldnt work for me but i had trouble explaining myself. I think it has something to do with wrapping certain sections in document.ready since for your snippet i should have the code wrapped in document.ready so it could find the element. I thought i should keep all the dom related stuff seperate. I have http://jsfiddle.net/u3wu7wh8/ the part that i want you to help me fit together that pertains to the code is `function getInput()` `function compare()`

Comment: @user2537537 Just checked your fiddle. Keep it simple. What exactly would you like to do?

Comment: the code gets random numbers adds them together and check to see if the  the result is the same as the user input. this will be a small part of the code I will add multiplying and find the percentage will be next

Answer (score 0):

It remains unclear to me what you want to accomplish.

I made some code that might be somewhere near what you want.

```js
jQuery().ready(function()
{
  var startValue = $('input[name="the_input"]').val();
  $('form').submit(function()
  {
    var currentValue = $('input[name="the_input"]').val();
    $('body').append('<br />' + startValue + ' - ' + currentValue + ' = ' + (startValue - currentValue));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="10" name="the_input" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="go!" />
</form>
```